# get from array what's not in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of ids and I need to check which of them do not match any of the ids in mongo collection. Is it possible? I know I can get all from mongo that's not in the array, but can I do the opposite? Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can do this in one way or another.  Can you show what you have tried and where you are having problems?

Comment: I have't tried anything, I don't know where to start. If I have a collection with 'id1', 'id2','id3','id4','id5' values in _id field, I know I can use mycollection.find({ _id: { $nin: [ 'id1','id2','id3','id6' ]} }) to get 'id4', 'id5'. But what do I need to do to get 'id6'?

Comment: @chibis See the question linked to in the duplicate message at the top of the page.